# I2C programming ATTiny88

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, i2c, programming, attiny

I am beginner at programming uC's. I have read all the tutorials on what is I2C and how it works, but I couldnt find any help specific on how to create a connection between my sensor and ATTiny88 ([ATTiny88 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8008.pdf).

I use SHT21 sensor ([SHT21 datasheet](http://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity/Sensirion_Humidity_SHT21_Datasheet_V4.pdf)) and want to communicate with ATTiny88 (MUC sends command to getData, and then sensors sends to MUC back the data (temperature, humidity)) - can someone help me guide through?

Once you help me, I'll understand it for future, but I really need a jump start here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have done I2C Communications for the Atmega32 and I interfaced a temperature sensor. Looking at the datasheet ATtiny and atmega has the same registers for I2C Communications. So you can use the following code I made for I2C Communication

This function will write the data to the I2C bus:

```
void i2c_write(unsigned char data)
{
  TWDR = data ;
  TWCR = (1<< TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
  while ((TWCR & (1 <<TWINT)) == 0);
}
```

This function will start the I2C Communication:

```
void i2c_start(void)
{
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTA) | (1 << TWEN);
  while ((TWCR & (1 << TWINT)) == 0);
}
```

This function will stop the communication:

```
void i2c_stop()
{
  TWCR = (1<< TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWSTO);
}
```

This function will initiate the I2C bus:

```
void i2c_init(void)
{
  TWSR=0x00;            
  TWBR=0x47;            
  TWCR=0x04;            
}
```

Now you can use these functions in you main

```
int main (void)
{
  i2c_init();   
  i2c_start();          
  i2c_write(address);   
  i2c_write(address);   
  i2c_stop();           
  while(1);         
  return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** Make the last bit of your address to 0 for `writing` and 1 `reading` from the i2c bus

Answer (score 3):

you should try to check examples:

http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY88.aspx?tab=documents

I see plenty of example on the I2C.

You should read them, understand them than try to implement them for your own application.

Regards,
Mathieu L.

Comment: The probably i dont know which one of those documents i need to select. Because, unless i'm blind, i cannot find in titles of those docs "I2C communication" nor "communicating with sensor". You have to consider i'm a beginner in this, trying to learn before applying to university..

Comment: Look in the brief descriptions, as well as the titles.  Also, look for "TWI" (Two Wire Interface) - one description says "TWI (I2C compatible)".